# How CPython detects where to find pool_header after reference count goes down to zero?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

Recently I read an article about CPython memory model: https://rushter.com/blog/python-memory-managment/. The article shows the following structure that CPython uses to manage single pool:

```
struct pool_header {
   union { block *_padding;
           uint count; } ref;          /* number of allocated blocks    */
   block *freeblock;                   /* pool's free list head         */
   struct pool_header *nextpool;       /* next pool of this size class  */
   struct pool_header *prevpool;       /* previous pool       ""        */
   uint arenaindex;                    /* index into arenas of base adr */
   uint szidx;                         /* block size class index        */
   uint nextoffset;                    /* bytes to virgin block         */
   uint maxnextoffset;                 /* largest valid nextoffset      */
};
```

The thing that I don't get is how CPython obtains this header to update if some block became free? Am I right that it relies on some low level trick that if you allocate a page of 4Kb size then it's pointer is somehow aligned and you can detect the start of the page by zeroing out several bits (possibly 12, because 2^12=4096) of blocks address? Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just [rounds the block address down](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0/Objects/obmalloc.c#L1029) to the nearest pool-aligned value:

```c
/* Round pointer P down to the closest pool-aligned address <= P, as a poolp */
#define POOL_ADDR(P) ((poolp)_Py_ALIGN_DOWN((P), POOL_SIZE))
```

While the rounding is essentially as you hypothesized, it is valid not because of the low-level trick you hypothesized, but simply because CPython manually ensures pools have the necessary alignment. When CPython allocates the big chunk of memory used for an arena's pools, it [sets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0/Objects/obmalloc.c#L1619-L1627) the arena's `pool_address` to the first pool-aligned address in that big chunk of memory:

```c
    /* pool_address <- first pool-aligned address in the arena
       nfreepools <- number of whole pools that fit after alignment */
    arenaobj->pool_address = (block*)arenaobj->address;
    arenaobj->nfreepools = MAX_POOLS_IN_ARENA;
    excess = (uint)(arenaobj->address & POOL_SIZE_MASK);
    if (excess != 0) {
        --arenaobj->nfreepools;
        arenaobj->pool_address += POOL_SIZE - excess;
    }
```